# Flipping a binary in a string

Tags: python, string

I am new to python and coding in general. So what I am trying to achieve is to flip each bit in a binary string (for eg. if I input '110' the output should be '001'). I specifically need to use the **while loop** and I need to define it as a function. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
def flip(binary_string):
    new_string= ''
    i=0
    while i<len(binary_string):
        if i == '0':
            new_string=new_string+ '1'
        if i == '1':
            new_string= new_string+ '0'
        i=i+1    
    return new_string
```

however it just returns the empty new_string as defined in the beginning. What's wrong with my code? any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were comparing the array index and not the element. Fixed that in the code below.

```
def flip(binary_string):
    new_string= ''
    i=0
    while i<len(binary_string):
        if binary_string[i] == '0':
            new_string=new_string+ '1'
        if binary_string[i] == '1':
            new_string= new_string+ '0'
        i=i+1    
    return new_string


flip("100")
>>> 011
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions:

```
while True:
    print(''.join(['0' if int(i) else '1' for i in input('Your Binary: ')]))`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flip(binary_string):
    new_string= ''
    i=0
    while i<len(binary_string):
        if binary_string[i] == '0':
            new_string=new_string+ '1'
        if binary_string[i] == '1':
            new_string= new_string+ '0'
        i=i+1    
    return new_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing **i** with '0' and '1', and you need to compare **binary_string**[i] :

```
def flip(binary_string):
    new_string= ''
    i=0
    while i<len(binary_string):
        if binary_string[i] == '0': # HERE
            new_string=new_string+ '1'
        if binary_string[i] == '1': # HERE
            new_string= new_string+ '0'
        i=i+1    
    return new_string
```